# How to conveniently pass parameters only if they are not nil in swift?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

Say I have a function with definition

```
func someInitialiser(paramA : String = "defaultA", paramB : Int = 23, paramC : Double = 99.99) {

    //initialisation using parameters

}
```

I don't want the values within the function to be optional, hence the use of default values for the case that no parameter is given.

However, when I want to call the function, I have a bunch of values to be given as parameters which are indeed optional.

As far as I'm aware you cannot pass a nil value into the function and have it fall back on the default value since the function does not take an optional input.

So it seems to me the only way to do this would be

```
if paramA == nil && paramB == nil && paramC == nil { someInitialiser() }
if paramA == nil && paramB == nil && paramC != nil { someInitialiser(paramC: paramC) }
if paramA == nil && paramB != nil && paramC == nil { someInitialiser(paramB: paramB) }
if paramA == nil && paramB != nil && paramC != nil { someInitialiser(paramB: paramB, paramC: paramC) }
if paramA != nil && paramB == nil && paramC == nil { someInitialiser(paramA: paramA) }
...
```

This has up to 2^(number of parameters) possible function calls for those with more parameters, so clearly isn't too nice to write.

It would be much simpler to be able to do something like

```
someInitialiser(paramA: paramA ?? NULL, paramB: paramB ?? NULL, paramC: paramC ?? NULL)
```

So that if the values were nil it would pass no parameter at all into the function so that it relies on the default ones in the definition.

I know an alternative is to also provide the default values when the function is called, using coalescence similar to above, though it would be nice to not have to repeat them outside the definition.

Comment: In Swift there is no way to say `paramA: default`. There is `Optional<Wrapped>.map(_:)` and `Optional<Wrapped>.flatMap(_:)`, but that probably wouldn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two functions:

```
someInitialiser(paramA: String?, paramB: Int?) {
   someInitializer(paramA: paramA ?? "defaultA", paramB: paramB ?? 23)
}

someInitialiser(paramA: String, paramB: Int) {
   ...
}
```

You are really overthinking the problem. If you want default values for `nil`, then `??` is the correct solution. If you don't want to use it outside the function, then you have to let the parameters to be optional and use `??` inside.

Comment: Maybe I was, though I wanted check I understood the semantics correctly and that there was no notion of equivalence in passing a nil parameter and not passing a parameter at all. 
My issue with optionals inside the function is that allowing nil values as well as default parameters means that the nils also have to be set to the default within the function, again meaning 2 copies of the defaults must be maintained.
Anyway the function does have a lot of parameters and is likely to be called from multiple places so the enclosing function seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the issue right , you should make your function parameter optional using ? sign and use the Nil-Coalescing Operator before calling the function or an if statement ( whichever you prefer )

```
    if yourParameter != nil {
         doSomething
    }
```

or using

```
    yourParameter != nil ? assignValue : assign defaultValue
```